# Why hadoop hdfs command: hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNodes is not work?

Tags: hadoop

I try to re-read the hosts and exclude files to update the set of Datanodes that are allowed to connect to the Namenode, after I finished the configuration, I execute "hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNodes"，but it does't work.

My hadoop version is 3.1.2 32bit, os is centos 7 64bit.

```
<property>
     <name>dfs.hosts</name>
     <value>/opt/install/hadoop-3.1.2/etc/hadoop/dfs.hosts</value>
</property>
```

after i execute the refresh command, the console display:
2019-07-07 09:31:15,468 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Refresh nodes successful